# How to grant permission in C# mysql backup database

Tags: c#, mysql

The error message: Access to the path 'C:\backupSALES.sql' is denied.

Here is mycode:

```
    private void BackupSALES()
    {
        string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=1234;database=sales;";
        string file = "C:\\backupSALES.sql";
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    mb.ExportToFile(file); //PROMTS AN ERROR
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: move your database out of C drive, or a place like Documents where user have file write permission

Comment: how about creating a sub-folder under the root drive and after that make sure you set the permissions on that folder. read up on `setting Folder Permissions` as well

Comment: ok thank you Mostafiz and MethodMan

Comment: string file = @"C:\\Users\Harold\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Final Sales and Inventory System\backupSALES.sql"; I did try this but if I access this to another pc the file path changes.